# TYPO3 crop image in fluid

Tags: typo3

I have croped image in BE. And how to show croped image in the fluid?

I have crope field:

```
crop => '{"default":{"cropArea":{"height":0.24482758620689654,"width":0.4379310344827
         586,"x":0,"y":0.5586206896551724},"selectedRatio":"16:9","focusArea":null}}' (151 chars)
```

I tried in fluid:

```
<f:image image="{file}" crop="{file.crop}" class="main-img"/>
```

Thank a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

As I know you dont need to tell the f:image ViewHelper anything about the cropping if you only use the default cropvariant. But I had some problems with Mittwald hosted websites - the GraphicsMagick version there was not able to crop somehow (on other Mittwald hosted sites it worked witht the same GM version).
So I just switched to ImageMagick on the sites which had problems with cropping in the frontend and then it worked.
If there is a problem with GM and cropping, default Content Elements won't even show the cropped variant in backend preview (Text and Media Elements)

Answer (score 0):

The `crop` attribute is meant for manual cropping of images. What you are looking for is [the `cropVariant` attribute](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Image.html#cropvariant). If you did not add any crop variants yourself, you will most likely at least have the `default` crop variant, so your snippet should look like this:

```
<f:image image="{file}" cropVariant="default" class="main-img"/>
```

For every additional crop variant you add another `<f:image/>` to render the image for that crop variant.

Comment: As I understand I have to make my own view helper to use crop field and show image with that crop attributes ?

Comment: Are you trying to use it on `<source>`  or `srcset`?
I don't think it is necessary... you can for example use it like this `{f:uri.image(image:myimage,cropVariant:'default)}` this returns just the path to the image