# Typo3 Backend image cropping / manipulation tool not working anymore after upgrade from 7 LTS to 8 LTS

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x

i need help.

I upgraded Typo3 7.6.27 to 8.7.x twice. But allways the crop function (image cropping tool - image manipulation) in Backend are igrnored after Upgrade.

Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I think the v8 cropping / imageManipulation works have been non breaking. afaik, existing tca configs are migrated on the fly.

However, you may want to read at least the following docs, and maybe adapt your TCA:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/8.7/Changelog/8.6/Feature-75880-ImplementMultipleCroppingVariantsInImageManipulationTool.html
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/8.7/Changelog/8.7/Feature-79812-AllowOverridingCropVariantsForImageManipulation.html
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/7.6/Changelog/7.2/Feature-65585-AddTCATypeImage_manipulation.html

Additionally, the documentation viewer of the install tool may be useful since it provides a search.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using ImageMagick as Image-Manipulation-Tool.

Comment: Maybe related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50293342/typo3-crop-image-in-fluid/50305772#50305772

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with TYPO3 8.7.24 and GraphicsMagic.
Using ImageMagick instead helped for me too.